# Write image downloaded in the media content

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am writing an app who download some images from a remote server. I try to save them in the gallery but I got a `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` required due to a Permission Denial.

I do not understand why because I set up the permission in the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.seb.sebastien.reddit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea why the permission denial happens as I add the permission. For information, I do not have an Android Device, I use the emulator. SDK use is API 26.

Thanks

Comment: is your app crashing if yes then add crash logs to further investiage your problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

For Android Running on Android 6.0 (API level 23) and above , we need to add runtime permission to work, you can follow this link  [Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

----Updated ----

Code reference

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect catch!

Comment: Ok ,edited , i will keep this in mind while giving answer to questions :)

Answer (score 0):

For `TargetSDK 23` or higher, you need to give runtime permission As per Android's guideline. Check this link for code snippet and more description.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for permission to allow run time operation in splash activity in `onCreate` or before download process of image.

```
if (!checkPermission()) {
        openActivity();
    } else {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            requestPermissionAndContinue();
        } else {
            openActivity();
        }
    }
```

Add this method outside `onCreate`.

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private boolean checkPermission() {

        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ;
    }

private void requestPermissionAndContinue() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            alertBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.permission_necessary));
            alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.storage_permission_is_encessary_to_wrote_event);
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            , READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
            Log.e("", "permission denied, show dialog");
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        openActivity();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {

            boolean flag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                openActivity();
            } else {
                finish();
            }

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void openActivity() {
  //add your further process after giving permission or to download images from remote server.
}
```

happy Coding.